# Python change list iteration order

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have a python list that looks like this:

```
my_list = [2, 4, 1 ,0, 3]
```

My goal is to iterate over this list in a manner where the next index is the current value and then to append all the index in another list and then stop the iteration once a cycle is over. Hence,

> Starting from 0 it contains the value 2 so you go to index 2.
> Index 2 contains the value 1 so you go to index 1
> Index 1 contains the value 4 so you go to index 4
> Index 4 contains the value 3 so you go to index 3
> Index 3 contains the value 0 so you go to index 0

and the new_list looks like this:

```
new_list = [0,2,1,4,3]
```

My attempt:

```
In [14]: my_list = [2,4,1,0,3]

In [15]: new_list =[]

In [16]: for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
    ...:     if i in new_list:
    ...:         break
    ...:     else:
    ...:         new_list.append(i)
    ...:         i=j
    ...: print(new_list)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is obviously not working. Specifically, that **i=j** line has no effect since the for loop goes back to the initial counter. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Say I start with i=0 and then I switch to i=my_list[i] and so forth.

Comment: iterators feed out the list in whatever order they are defined to return. in this case its the order of the original list.   if your original structure was a a dict that was keyed by index position you could iterate for the size of that dict and for each key pull out its value and use that as the key to extract the next value.  something like that might work foryou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `while` loop is a better structure here; set `i` to point to the first element in `my_list` and then iterate until you find `i` in `new_list`:

```py
my_list = [2,4,1,0,3]
new_list = []

i = 0
while i not in new_list:
    new_list.append(i)
    i = my_list[i]
    
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```py
[0, 2, 1, 4, 3]
```

Note the code assumes that all values in `my_list` are valid indexes into `my_list`. If this is not the case, you would need to add a test for that and break the loop at that point. For example:

```py
my_list = [2,4,5,0,3]
new_list = []

i = 0
while i not in new_list:
    new_list.append(i)
    i = my_list[i]
    if i not in range(len(my_list)):
        break
        
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```py
[0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. using variable swapping you can reassign rather than appending and creating a new variable

```
my_list = [2,4,1,0,3]

n= len(my_list)

for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(0,n-i-1):
       if my_list[j] > my_list[j+1]:
           my_list[j], my_list[j+1] = my_list[j+1],my_list[j] 
print(my_list)
```